# How to add subtitles to ExoPlayer with Android TV VideoSupportFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, android-tv

I have an Android TV app based on Google Android TV samples repository and I'm not able to show subtitles. I don't have any crash of the app, the subtitles are simply not shown, as far as I understood from my investigations there's no Android view to render them.

My *playback* fragment (the one that plays the video) implements a `VideoSupportFragment`, an Android Leanback fragment with a `Surface` integrated into the layout to render the video.

That's how I create the subtitles:

```kotlin
        val subtitles = videoRepository.listSubtitles("m" + video.id).mapIndexed { index, it ->
            val builder = MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(
                    Uri.parse("http://192.168.129.9:3000/api/subtitles/${it.id}")
                )
                .setMimeType(MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT)
                .setLanguage(it.lang)
                .setId(it.id.toString())

            if (index == 0) {
                builder.setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
            }

            builder.build()
        }

        val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(video.videoUri)
            .setSubtitleConfigurations(subtitles)
            .build()
```

And this is where I *connect* (I think at least...) the ExoPlayer to the fragment containing the video surface:

```kotlin
private fun prepareGlue(localExoplayer: ExoPlayer) {
        ProgressTransportControlGlue(
            requireContext(),
            LeanbackPlayerAdapter(
                requireContext(),
                localExoplayer,
                PLAYER_UPDATE_INTERVAL_MILLIS.toInt()
            ),
            onProgressUpdate
        ).apply {
            host = VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost(this@PlaybackFragment)
            title = video.name
            subtitle = video.year.toString()
            // Enable seek manually since PlaybackTransportControlGlue.getSeekProvider() is null,
            // so that PlayerAdapter.seekTo(long) will be called during user seeking.
            // TODO(gargsahil@): Add a PlaybackSeekDataProvider to support video scrubbing.
            isSeekEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

The full code is here (it's an open source project): [PlaybackFragment.kt#L125](https://github.com/CouchBuddy/couch-buddy-android-tv/blob/subtitles/app/src/main/java/com/android/tv/reference/playback/PlaybackFragment.kt#L125)

and is based on this AndroidTV sample:
https://github.com/android/tv-samples/blob/main/ReferenceAppKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/android/tv/reference/playback/PlaybackFragment.kt

Answer (score 0):

The leanback `VideoSupportFragment` inflates `lb_playback_fragment.xml` which does not inlcude an exoplayer `SubtitleView`. As discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6587) the easiest way is to override `lb_playback_fragment.xml` and include a `SubtitleView` inside it. The file copied from the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/playback_fragment_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionGroup="false">

    <androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playback_fragment_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionGroup="false" />

    <androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playback_controls_dock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionGroup="true" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SubtitleView
            android:id="@+id/leanback_subtitles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then inside your fragment code you can use the `SubtitleView` as a text output to show the subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated version with media3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/playback_fragment_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionGroup="false">

    <androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playback_fragment_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionGroup="false" />

    <androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playback_controls_dock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transitionGroup="true" />

    <androidx.media3.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <androidx.media3.ui.SubtitleView
            android:id="@+id/leanback_subtitles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.media3.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```